# Establishing a second connection in Rails app without using abstract class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Initially, this worked to create a second connection:

```
class OtherDb < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection :crawler_production

  def self.notify_changes
    sql = ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, ["UPDATE ...", attr1, attr2])
    connection.execute(sql)
```

However, this prevents me from instantiating OtherDb. I would get an error that I can't instantiate an abstract class. So I tried changing to this:

```
class VtigerDb
  def initialize
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:crawler_production)
  end

  def notify_changes
    sql = ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, ["UPDATE ...", attr1, attr2])
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
  end
```

However, this gives me another error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'original_db.other_db_table' doesn't exist:
```

How can I access a second connection in a Rails app, without forcing that class to be an abstract class?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the octopus gem](https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus). You can use it for database sharding in a Rails app.